# Adding specific new lines until getting a specific number line python

Tags: python, file

I have large number of files with different line numbers and same column numbers(10 columns) in a directory. I want to loop through all the files and perform the following operation.

1. If number of lines in file is smaller than 20
2. Add new lines with value(1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0) with same column number (10) until file has 20 lines
3. If line number between 20 and 40, then repeat step 2 but upto 40 lines

the code below but I don't know how to complete to get actual results

```
    os.chdir('./directory/')
    names={}
    for fn in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    with open(fn) as f:
     names[fn]=sum(1 for line in f)
     line=f.readlines()
     x=[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
     if names[fn] < 20:
       .....
     if names[fn]>20 and names[fn]<40
      .....
```

Comment: how are columns represented in the file? Space separated numbers?

Comment: how would you like the value(1110110110) to be written in the file?

Comment: Columns are separated with space. The space have to be between numbers in the line.

Comment: @gEngW I have provided you with a solution, although it depends upon you on how  you implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of a workaround of your code, where I am assuming the `x = [1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]` is a string datatype variable. If not, you can always convert it into one and get it done with. Also, it does a sanity check of the file and the number of lines it already has, shortening it by a margin and then doing the process required. Hope it helps

```
os.chdir('./directory/')
names={}
x=[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
for fn in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    with open(fn) as f:
       line=f.readlines()
       i = len(line)
    if i < 20:
       with open(fn, 'a') as input_file:
            while i < 20:
                input_file.write(x)
                input_file.write("\n")
                i+=1 
    if i > 20 and i < 40
          with open(fn, 'a') as input_file:
            while i < 40:
                input_file.write(x)
                input_file.write("\n")
                i+=1
```